# How to change elements' color on hover

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a mouseover event that turns divs blue when I hover over them. I am looping over each div with forEach and expect it to turn blue when hovered over. However, the code is not working at all. I have determined that the nodelist has a length of 0, but I am not sure why that is. I want it to stay blue even after I stop hovering over it, which is why I am using js.

```
var form = document.getElementById("inputForm");
var clearButton = document.getElementById("clear");
var input = form.querySelector("input");

//Starts function that does everything

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

//Prevents browser from refreshing on submit

    e.preventDefault();

input.disabled = true;
var boxInput = input.value;
var gridContainer = document.getElementById("gridContainer");
console.log(boxInput);

for (var i = 0; i <= boxInput * boxInput - 1; i++) {

//Creates a certain number of rows and columns based on user input

    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns =  `repeat(${boxInput}, 1fr)`;
    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateRows =  `repeat(${boxInput}, 1fr)`;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    console.log(div);
    div.className = "grid";
    gridContainer.appendChild(div);
}
});

var hoverElement = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');

hoverElement.forEach(function() {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    });
  });

clearButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
   input.disabled = false;
   input.value = 0;
   var divs = gridContainer.getElementsByClassName('grid');
   while (divs.length > 0) {
    gridContainer.removeChild(divs[0]);
   }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps just CSS? `.grid:hover {backround-color: blue}`

Comment: Why not use CSS?

Comment: Please include a [mre].

Comment: `forEach(function() {` you are not setting a parameter to get the passed element for the `forEach` callback, eg `forEach(function(element) {`. You should be getting an error in the JS Console about your `element.addEventListener()` line due to this

Answer (score 1):

if you try to make a hover affect, become blue when mouse is enter and return (not blue) when the mouse leave, it's easier to use css.

```
.grid:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

but if you what the div after the mouse leave to stay blue it's right to use js. however i believe you just forget to add "element" in function that used in each element inside hoverElement.

```
hoverElement.forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    });
});
```

Comment: I should have specified I do want it to stay blue when I stop hovering. I added in element and it still does not want to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on a previous answer, *"I should have specified I do want it to stay blue when I stop hovering..."*, it seems you want the grid boxes to stay *blue* once they're no longer hovered.

This makes using a `CSS` only solution pretty hard (to not say impossible) so we need to do it dynamically using `JavaScript`.

The idea is simple, we'll use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) on the `#grid-container` instead of applying a `mouseover` event handler to all the grid boxes. We'll have only one `mouseover` event applied to `#grid-container` element which will handle changing the background color of the grid boxes.

We'll create a new `CSS` class, let's call it `.blue` for example, that will be applied to the boxes to change their background colors to *blue*.

The process is simple: once the `#grid-container` gets hovered we'll see if the mouse is on a box and if yes we'll apply our `.blue` class to that box (unless it has already been applied).

That might sound hard or complicated but believe me it's not, the following code snippet should make things even clearer.

```js
/**
 * The solution will work with elements already found in the DOM as well as dynamically created elements.
 * The solution illustrates both cases.
 */


/*
 * Select the "#grid-element" so we can apply our event handler (mouseover) 
 * The dynamicBoxes is not really necessary, it only holds dynamically created elemnt to showcase that the solution works on dynamically created elements
 */
const gridContainer = document.getElementById('grid-container'),
  dynamicBoxes = [];

// loop counter
let i = 4;

// just create some box elements...
for (; i++ < 8;) {
  const box = document.createElement('div');
  box.textContent = `Am a grid element dynamically created (No: ${i})`;
  box.classList.add('box');
  dynamicBoxes.push(box);
}

// append those boxes to "#grid-container"
gridContainer.append(...dynamicBoxes);

// the mouseover event listener
gridContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  // "e.target" holds the element being hovered, i.e the one that the mouse is over.
  const cls = e.target.classList;

  /* halt the function execution if:
  *     - the hovered element is not a box (it doesn't have the ".box" class
        - OR that box already has the ".blue" class
  */
  if (!cls.contains('box') || cls.contains('blue')) return;

  // apply the ".blue" class to the hovered box
  cls.add('blue');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#grid-container {
  padding-inline: 15px;
}

.box {
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #c3c3c3;
}

.box.blue {
  background-color: #00f;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid-container">
  <div class="box">Am a grid element already in the DOM (No: 1)</div>
  <div class="box">Am a grid element already in the DOM (No: 2)</div>
  <div class="box">Am a grid element already in the DOM (No: 3)</div>
  <div class="box">Am a grid element already in the DOM (No: 4)</div>
</div>
```